# Spring MVC Populate Modal Form

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a modal form (using `bootstrap`) that I use to add a user. This form is wired to a 'addUser' method via `RequestMapping` in my Controller. Adding a user works fine.

Is there a simple way I can populate the same modal form to edit existing user details after clicking an edit button?  Do I have to make an `AJAX` call to a `REST endpoint` to populate the form, or is there a better way of doing this?

I'm using Spring Boot.

Thanks,
Jerry

Comment: You'll need to provide more information to get a good answer. The best way to do this depends on what view technology you're using. If you're using something on the server (such as Thymeleaf), then you can populate the form in the HTML that's served to the browser. If all of your view logic is on the client, then you'll need a different approach.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for not providing enough info.  I have created a simple project based on the [Handling Form Submission](http://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission) example.  But instead of the Greetings form, I have created a User form, and placed the form into a Modal container of Bootstrap.

Comment: So, when I click a 'Add User' button, the modal form is shown, and I can enter the user details, hit submit, and the details are stored in a in memory database.

The problem I have, is when I click a 'Edit' button, I would like the modal form to come up, and be populated with the user's details I'd like to edit, without refreshing the page.
The only solution I can think of, is making a AJAX call with JQuery, and populating the form that way.  Is there a better way of doing this, using the Spring MVC framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AJAX request would be your best bet, otherwise you'd have to load all the editable user properties ahead of time when you load the page of existing users and store them in memory or on the page somehow.  It's not the most efficient solution though because you're loading all those properties for all users, every time you reload the page.  If you only have a handful of users, that might be ok for you, but if you're dealing with a large set of users, then that will make for longer request times.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can make a ajax request and get the modal details in form of Json or Xml.
Below example retrieve the user details and set it into modal form variables like **userName**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "Url to get the response",
        cache: false,               
        data:'userId=' + $("#userId").val(),
        success: function(response){
            var obj = JSON.parse(response);
            $('#userName').val(obj.userName);
        },
        error: function(){                      
            alert('Error while request..');
        }
    });
```